# Saving DataStream data into MongoDB / converting DS to DF

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am able to save a Data Frame to mongoDB but my program in spark streaming gives a datastream ( kafkaStream ) and I am not able to save it in mongodb neither i am able to convert this datastream to a dataframe. Is there any library or method to do this? Any inputs are highly appreciated.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils

object KafkaSparkStream {

    def main(args: Array[String]){

        val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("KafkaReceiver")
        val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))
        val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 
            "localhost:2181","spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("topic" -> 25))
        kafkaStream.print()

        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()
    }
}
```

Save a DF to mongodb - SUCCESS

```scala
val mongoDbFormat = "com.stratio.datasource.mongodb"
val mongoDbDatabase = "mongodatabase"
val mongoDbCollection = "mongodf"

val mongoDbOptions = Map(
    MongodbConfig.Host -> "localhost:27017",
    MongodbConfig.Database -> mongoDbDatabase,
    MongodbConfig.Collection -> mongoDbCollection
)

//with DataFrame methods
 dataFrame.write
    .format(mongoDbFormat)
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .options(mongoDbOptions)
    .save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the underlying `RDD` from the `DStream` using `foreachRDD`, transform it to a `DataFrame` and use your `DF` function on it.

The easiest way to transform an RDD to a DataFrame is by first transforming the data into a schema, represented in Scala by a `case class`

```
case class Element(...)

val elementDStream = kafkaDStream.map(entry => Element(entry, ...))
elementDStream.foreachRDD{rdd =>
    val df = rdd.toDF
    df.write(...)
}
```

Also, watch out for Spark 2.0 where this process will completely change with the introduction of *Structured Streaming*, where a MongoDB connection will become a sink.

Comment: what should be in this field Element(entry, ...))? Sorry, I am new to scala.

Comment: @Goutam imagine you have a `case class Tweet(hande:String, msg:String, timestamp:Long)`  and a stream of tweets as tuples of `(handle, language, message, timestamp)`, then you would do something like: `map(entry => Tweet(entry._1, entry._3, entry._4))`. Provide the data to construct an instance of the `case class`

Comment: Its working fine. But when i do df.write() with the database then i get the below error : 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.typeOfObject()Lscala/PartialFunction;
 at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.schema.MongodbSchema.com$stratio$datasource$mongodb$schema$MongodbSchema$$convertToStruct(MongodbSchema.scala:65)
 at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.schema.MongodbSchema$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(MongodbSchema.scala:43)
 at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.schema.MongodbSchema$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(MongodbSchema.scala:43)

Comment: This seems to not work inside the loop.

dataFrame.write
    .format(mongoDbFormat)
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .options(mongoDbOptions)
    .save()